# select from multiple tables -PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

im trying to do this query

```
SELECT category_request.request_id
FROM category_request, event, user
WHERE category_request.category_name = event.category_name 
AND user.user_id = event.moderator_id
```

and when im trying to run on my database it work's fine as shown here:

[image]

but for some reason(maybe because im doing a join?) im getting an error:

> mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

and i know for sure that only need one colum from the table
and here's the php file

```
<?php
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/config.php'); 


/*  $event_name = $_POST["event_name"];
    $event_description = $_POST["event_description"];
     $event_date = $_POST["event_date"];
    $event_time = $_POST["event_time"];
    $max_members = $_POST["max_members"]; 
    $ack_needed = $_POST["ack_needed"];
    $category_name = $_POST["category_name"];
    $event_location = $_POST["event_location"]; */

    $event_name = (isset($_POST['event_name']) ? $_POST['event_name'] : '');
    $event_description = (isset($_POST['event_description']) ? $_POST['event_description'] : '');
    $event_date = (isset($_POST['event_date']) ? $_POST['event_date'] : '');
    $event_time = (isset($_POST['event_time']) ? $_POST['event_time'] : '');
    $max_members = (isset($_POST['max_members']) ? $_POST['max_members'] : '');
    $ack_needed = (isset($_POST['ack_needed']) ? $_POST['ack_needed'] : '');
    $category_name = (isset($_POST['category_name']) ? $_POST['category_name'] : '');
    $event_location = (isset($_POST['event_location']) ? $_POST['event_location'] : '');
    $moderator_id = (isset($_POST['moderator_id']) ? $_POST['moderator_id'] : '');



    $result = mysqli_prepare( $con, "SELECT category_request.request_id FROM category_request, event, user
        WHERE category_request.category_name = event.category_name AND user.user_id = event.moderator_id")                                              

    or die(mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result,"i", $category_id)
    or die(mysqli_error($con)); 


    mysqli_stmt_execute($result)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));







   /* $statement = mysqli_prepare($con,     
    "INSERT INTO event (event_name, event_description, event_date
                                    , event_time, max_members, ack_needed, 
                                    category_name, moderator_id,event_location)     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")                                                                                    
    or die(mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssssisis", $event_name, $event_description, $event_date,   $event_time, $max_members, $ack_needed,                                                                                    
                                                                            , $category_name, $moderator_id,$event_location)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement)
    or die(mysqli_error($con)); */

    $response = array(); 
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);

    mysqli_close($con)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make a prepared statement instead of just using `mysqli_query`. If you really did mean to use a prepared statement, as in using a placeholder for your `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` function, then you need to include `?` as your placeholder in your prepared statement.

Buuuut, since I don't see `category_id` referenced anywhere in your query, maybe you need to use `mysqli_query` and fetch all results? Eg:

```
$result = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT category_request.request_id FROM category_request, event, user WHERE category_request.category_name = event.category_name AND user.user_id = event.moderator_id");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    // do something with $row
  }
} else {
  echo "no results";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i was looking for something like that for hours and i couldn't figure out for myself, you save me a lot of headache

Answer (score 2):

In your query :

```
$result = mysqli_prepare( $con, "SELECT category_request.request_id FROM category_request, event, user
        WHERE category_request.category_name = event.category_name AND user.user_id = event.moderator_id")  or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

there are no placeholders so `mysqli` doesn't know what to do when it gets to your `binding`.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result,"i", $category_id)
or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

The placeholder tells the driver where to put the bound value. So take out:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result,"i", $category_id) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

or put a placeholder, `?`, in your query so it can bind for you (I'm making wild assumptions below about your table structure, correct them if this is the correct implementation).

```
$result = mysqli_prepare( $con, "SELECT category_request.request_id FROM category_request, event, user
        WHERE category_request.category_name = event.category_name AND user.user_id = event.moderator_id and category_request.category_id = ?")  or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

For more examples see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: okay now im getting Unknown column ` 'category_request.category_id' in 'where clause' `, but clearly i have the column [link](http://imgur.com/a/nAfgd)

Comment: Yea... see the note before that code? `I'm making wild assumptions below about your table structure, correct them if this is the correct implementation` The `category_request.category_id` is a guess, put in the correct table and column it should match with.